# MongoDB authentication on Windows Sharded Cluster

Tags: windows, mongodb, authentication

I have been tasked to prepare a Sharded MongoDB Cluster on a windows environment. This is the first time I work with this product. I have been trying to get authentication on MongoDB 2.4 to work on this windows Sharded Cluster environment and it's not working. Once I enable the auth option  on the 3 configuration servers, the MongoS instance is unable to start, when I remove the auth option, the MongoS instance works without any issues.

Can someone please shed some light on how to get authentication to work? The documentation mentions a "KeyFile" option but I've tried to use it in windows and the option is not recognized.

Thanks everyone.

Jaime Gonzalez

Comment: What error are you getting in the `mongos` logs? Authentication works fine in a sharded cluster infrastructure on Windows (the only difference is that file permissions aren't checked).                         Have you got the same "keyFile" configured on each `mongod`, `mongod config` and `mongos` and do the processes all start up referencing the keyfile?

Answer (score 1):

Note Key file permissions are not checked on Windows systems.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/generate-key-file/